# Поиск по БД с помощью формы на сайте по множеству параметров

Tags: поиск, база-данных

Подскажите материалы по созданию формы, с помощью которой можно будет выполнять поиск по БД с возможностью выбора параметров (т.е. юзер нажимает "Расширенный поиск" и у него много-много кружочков появляется, где можно поставить галочку и также одна строка, где вводится поисковое слово).

Буду очень благодарен за примеры таких кодов. И не обязательно поиск по БД MySQL, если есть возможность поиска по параметрам с использованием других технологий, то я буду благодарен вдвойне, если Вы их подскажите!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А что тут сложного!

1. Вариант - используем разные адреса обработчики, к примеру, `seach.php` - сценарий обработки обычного поиска, `seachbydetail.php` -сценарий обработки расширенного поиска.
2. Вариант на основе паттерна (не помню, как называется), где входной скрипт всегда один. Тогда указываем в качестве параметра, какой метод поиска используем и плюс необходимые этому методу переменные (пример, `index.php?action=seach&{необходимые методу переменные}` или `index.php?action=seachbydetail&{необходимые методу переменные}`).

По поводу, как сделать форму, тут много вариантов. Самое простое - 2 формы поиска с различными адресами обработчиками, но красивее сделать на JS (JQuery) динамическую.

Comment: Мне бы сам процесс поиска понять. По форме разберусь, по тому как эти данные записывать в переменные тоже. Но вот как с помощью PHP в MySQL искать по этим переменным?

Comment: ну тогда структуру таблицы приведите и поля по которым будет возможен поиск